# Sleep/Awake iPad/iPhone with Private Frameworks like IOKit or something else

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, iokit

I'm looking for a solution where i can send my device to sleep mode and wake it up if I want.

FYI - Those devices are placed on public places and are running in single app mode. We use Apple enterprise solution and our app is NOT in the App Store. So any nasty solution you got for me... please tell me!